# How do I use array each with async/await?

Tags: javascript

How do I check that every element pass the test if a test is async and can throw an error

```
const exists = async () => {//can throw an error}
const allExists = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].every(exists);
```

Comment: Use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all promises to resolve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use synchronous methods like `every` with functions that do asynchronous work, because the synchronous method won't wait for the asynchronous result. It's possible to write an `async` `every`, though:

```
async function every(array, callback) {
    for (const element of array) {
        const result = await callback(element);
        if (!result) {
           return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that because it relies on asynchronous information, it too delivers its result asynchronously. You have to `await` it (or use `.then`/`.catch`, etc.).

That version works in *series*, only calling the callback for the second entry when the callback for the first has finished its work. That lets you short-circuit (not call the callback for later entries when you already know the answer), but may make it take longer in overall time. Another approach is to do all of the calls in parallel, then check their results:

```
Promise.all(array.map(callback))
.then(flags => flags.every(Boolean))
.then(result => {
    // ...`result` will be `true` or `false`...
});
```

Comment: This will check every element of the array in sequence. Using `Promise.all` to check all elements in parallel is probably better

Comment: @darthmaim - I was just noting the series/parallel thing in the answer, I realized I'd omitted it. I wouldn't say parallel is necessarily better, it's very situation-dependent. But I should have flagged it up originally.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: "won't _wait_ for the asynchronous result."

Comment: Thanks @Andy - Took me four reads -- *four* -- to finally see it. I may need to up my font size. *sigh*